# Our Trigger.IO app is 9MB, is this too large & how can we reduce app loading time?

Tags: optimization, trigger.io

Our app is currently extremely slow when first booting up.
What are the key elements that contribute to app loading time and how can we accelerate that process?

We load very simple note objects into memory upon launch and intend to use plugins for native databases soon.

We plan on minifying as well as using native plugins for storage, what other strategies can we employ?

[This guest post](http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2012/10/25/guest-post-%E2%80%93-inside-hojoki%E2%80%99s-mobile-build-process/) by hojoki has been pretty helpful as well.

Comment: Could you provide more info about the devices/simulators you are testing on and what you mean by "extremely slow". Are you talking about the time from start to hiding launch image or from start to showing all the notes? What time frames are we talking about? Also: could you says something about whats done in your index.html (basic structure, when is your JS executed, ..).

Comment: FWIW, traditional performance techniques like minifying JavaScript probably aren't much use here - the files are all bundles locally so transmission is free. It won't hurt though!

Answer (score 0):

**Duplicate resources**

In trigger.io all resources (Android + iOS) are packaged together. E.g. the splash screen Android is included both in the iOS and Android build -- and vice versa. Perhaps that's one reason for the size?

And if so, building two separate apps, one per platform, may be one way to work around that issue. Obviously the ability to exclude non-platform resources would be even better, but that doesn't work right now.

**File size**

Run minification on all js/css, reduce png/jpeg file-sizes.

Comment: Thanks @sandstrom, we've actually gotten the app down to about 1.5mb's now :)